# Does every $x\in (0,1)$ have a base-3 expansion containing a 1?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I tried to argue that the answer is yes, by noting that $0.222...=1$ so if the number ends in an infinite string of $2$'s then we're done, and if not then at some point it is of the form $...20a_1a_2a_3...$ and then I tried to rewrite this using $0.2=0.1222...$ . Unfortunately I couldn't avoid carried digits from the infinite string of $1$'s all ending up giving $0$ or $2$.

I know that the numbers which can be written using only $0$ and $2$ are the Cantor Set, but I suspect that all of these numbers still have a representation containing a $1$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $x=.202020202\dots = .a_1 a_2 a_3\dots$ Could $a_1\le 1?$ No because then the most $.a_1 a_2 a_3\dots$ could be is $.1222222\dots = .20000000\dots < x.$ So $a_1=2.$

Thus $x = .2 a_2 a_3\dots.$ Could $a_2>0?$ No because then the smallest $.2 a_2 a_3\dots$ could be is $.210000\dots = .20222222\dots > x.$

So we have $x = .2 0 a_3\dots.$ Now multiply by $3^2$ to get $20.2020202\dots = 20.a_3\dots.$ Subtract $20$ from both sides to get $.2020202\dots = .a_3 a_4\dots.$ By what we did above, $a_3=2,a_4=0.$ Etc.

Answer (score 1):

Well, no. What about $0.\overline{02}_3$?

Comment: Is that not 0.01111111... ?

Comment: @LL No, it's not. Base $3$ expansion is unique except for terminating strings of digits, to which you can add $2$'s to the end and decrease the last digit.

Comment: Oh yes you are right, I was thinking in base 2 ^^

Comment: Then my point is that this is 0.01222222...

Comment: @LL No, because that would just be $0.02$. Notice the bar indicates it repeats.

Comment: Oh ok, you should indicate this notation then!

Comment: @LL3.14 That's pretty standard notation.